# Is it legit to use a rank-based transform for two linear regression in series?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, outliers

I have to perform two linear regressions in series, where the response of the first one is used as a predictor in the second. For the sake of introducing a common notation, let us say that the first model is:

```
Y1 ~ X1 + X2 + X3
```

and it outputs some predicted values for the Y1 variable, which then enters the second regression model:

```
Z ~ Y1 + Y2 + Y3
```

The problem is that the predicted values of Y1 are marred by outliers. Is it appropriate to perform a rank-based inverse normal transformation on such variable, before using it for the second regression model?

Notice that the transformation would be applied to the predictors, not to the response as it is usually the case.

In my situation dropping the outliers only leads to the appearance of more outliers. Besides, I have to make one of these models for each of ~50,000 genes, so manual intervention is not an option.

Comment: It seems like the utility of INTs is unclear, based on [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2921808/). This might be one of those issues where you simply have to try it out and see what happens. You can also always consider other techniques like dropping outliers (i.e. some thresholding), or switching the objective function, though these methods have their own pros and cons.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer, the paper was very useful. Dropping the outliers does not work: even more outliers appear... I updated the question to add more details.